# Excel webpart showing "Loading" but not showing the excel file

Tags: excel, excel-services, secure-store, excel-web-access-webpart

I am using an excel file which uses a `dataconnection` stored in dataconnection library. The dataconnection gets the data from sql server using Secure store and excel services.

I am trying to use the excel webpart to display this excel file. The Excel webpart is not able to display the excel file contents, It just has continuous loading message and symbol.

I am able to open the file using Excel client or Excel web viewer.
I dont see anything in logs with respect to the webpart. I have tried compatibility settings, etc. I am not sure, if I am barking the wrong tree?

Any ideas?